# What's the accepted way to write Java methods where return value may be invalid?

Tags: java

I come from a C programming background. I want to understand what's the best way to write Java API where a value is being returned, but it may be invalid.

I have a class implementing a Binary Search Tree. It has a method, getRootValue() which returns the root's value.

C code-

```
boolean getRootValue(int *answer) {
    if (root != null) {
        *answer = value;
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

On the user's end, this is what it will look like-

```
if (getRootValue(&answer)) {
    //process valid answer
}
```

The user calling this function will check the return, and only consider `answer` to be valid if the return value is `TRUE`.

Java skeleton code-

```
package algorithm;
class bst {
    node root;
    class node {
        int value;
        node left;
        node right
    }

    //getRootValue()
}
```

User's end-

```
package user;
import algorithm.bst;
...
//bst.getRootValue();
```

In Java, what would be the correct way (considering the root is only known to BST and not the user)? Should we send a special class object which contains both the boolean and the answer? If so, where should this class be defined?

Is there a different method? Should I think differently for my bst class implementation?

There are previous questions asking how to return multiple values. That's not exactly my question. I want to know the ideal way to implement this particular case, which possibly may not even require returning multiple objects.

Comment: Using interface would help here

Comment: In addition to the answer given by @EJP you could also consider throwing an exception if you receive bad user input.  This frees the inputs and outputs from having to serve two purposes.

Comment: C is a procedural language which treats memory as one large array.  Java is a memory managed language that works in terms of objects.  You seem to be making the assumption that a programming idiom that works in one language can be readily translated to the other.  This is not true more often than you would hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even write the method. There's nothing special about the root that you need a specific method to get its value. The entire method is redundant. You need something to get the root, and you need something to get the value out of any node (and its left and right children too).

I would write *two* methods:

1. `Node Tree.getRoot()`
2. `int Node.getValue()`.

The exceptional case you mention is met by returning `null` from `getRoot()`, which the caller can readily detect.

Comment: Sure, but I’m still curious on the proper java function signature of a method that might return invalid data... Would it just return null?

Answer (score 2):

From Java 8, you can use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as a return for unsure answer.

```
Optional<Integer> getRootValue() {
    return root != null ? Optional.of(value) : Optional.empty(); 
}
```

Then client code can use a lambda expression to process the value, if present, smoothly.

```
getRootValue().ifPresent(value -> {
    // process the value
    System.out.println(value);
})
```

Comment: This answer seems to fit this part of the question: "Should we send a special class object which contains both the boolean and the answer? If so, where should this class be defined?"

Comment: The qualified name of the class is java.util.Optional, which is part of the Java Core. Say it another way, unsure (optional) results are fully supported by Java since 8.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the absolute best way to do this, but in Java, I would recommend creating/using an exception. Then, the user could test if the return value is valid based on whether or not an exception was thrown.

```
int getRootValue(int answer) throws Exception{
    if (root != null){
        return value;
    }else{
        throw new NullPointerException("Root is null");
    }
}
```

on the user's end

```
try{
    myVal = getRootValue(answer);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(); //There was an error here
}
```

Comment: I would do the same, but not with `Exception`. I would create my own exception class.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto *I* would throw `NullPointerException` with a suitable message, but then I wouldn't write it this way anyway.

Comment: @EJP Edited with the NullPointerException. That was a good idea.

Comment: But the message isn't. The root may be null merely because nothing has been inserted into the tree yet, or everything has been deleted from it. It should be 'root *is* null', or 'tree is empty', or something more informative.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I would use NPE because it is about something being null. You don't need to write another exception for the same thing.

Comment: Unchecked exception should not be used for expected cases. Practice 1: don't use exception as conditional branching.